# Was Aniara demonstrating panspermia?

Tags: aniara

The ending didn't seem to fit any of the sociological or scientific themes of *Aniara*. The name of the story itself implies despair, and it continually devolves in each act. However by the nature of that final scene,

> Arriving at a lush water-covered planet in the Libra constellation that looks like a pristine young earth
>  [image: Destination planet in Lyra constellation]]
> carrying remains of her 8,000 passengers and algae
> [image: Jawbone and other human remains],

it seems to actually leave hope. Was it the film maker's intent to express the idea of panspermia?

*Please use spoiler text in your answers!*

Note [the director has confirmed](https://www.inverse.com/article/55884-aniara-movie-director-interview-pella-kagerman-says-this-is-climate-change) that the ending scene I am asking about is both true to the Swedish poem and a fundamental part of the story.

> Kågerman obtained permission to adapt Martinson’s poem thanks to the blessings of the poet’s daughters, Harriet and Eva. “They were very open-minded and excited about the film,” she says. “Their only concern was for us to stay true to the ending of the poem, which we also did.”

I have researched several online reviews and the all-important ending scene is normally glossed over, like in the case of this [horrible New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/16/movies/aniara-review.html) review. This could be to protect the quite shocking and unexpected ending, or just because the reviewer was too lazy to sit through a 110 minute film. But again, per the author that is an essential part of the story.

I am not inviting film critique or interpretations and such are not appropriate for this site. Only answers which reference intent are appropriate (staff interviews and canonical references). Was this ending chosen to show panspermia in action?

Comment: this *could* be answerable via a word from the production staff / screenplay writer. It's borderline opinion based, but the possibility is there that somebody involved w/ the production has something to say on the subject. I'm not voting to close on that basis for now

Comment: It's definitely not opinion-based. The final scene was very deliberate and specific. Some things can be left up to interpretation however people unfamiliar with the movie have no ability to judge what is or is not opinion-based, and certainly would be wise to abstain from doing so.

Comment: Just glancing through some summaries here... what exactly does the idea of panspermia have to do with the hopefulness of the ending?  Seems the film assumes the idea that there's life out in the black, not that it helps the ship or it's people in the slightest.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the poem and operetic adaptations Aniara is an epic of extinction, inspired by Martinsen gazing up at the Andromeda galaxy through a telescope one exceptionally clear evening in 1953, shortly after the Soviet Union conducted their first H-bomb test. He experienced sensations of being on a spaceship. I think if you asked this question of Harry Martinsen at the time he wrote it, the answer would simply be, no.

There is a bit of confusion about the clip in question, as it may not be included in every releases of the film. Directors had commented that a different US release was made because the original showed an erect penis, which could not be released in the US. And the [following review of both the opera and the film](https://www.pressreader.com/usa/the-new-york-review-of-books/20190815/281621011922582) seem to conclude that the clip in question is not shown in the main release:

> The film comes nearest to the original's poetic force in its final scene, in which the image of the Aniara as a galactic sarcophagus is fully realized, all life within extinguished, still light-years distant from Lyra.

They were obviously reviewing a different release of the film.

Concerning the modern film adaptation and the clip in question - as seen in the US - what is currently available from interviews and reviews seem to be conspicuously silent about that except for Variety magazine [which obliquely calls the ending](https://variety.com/2019/film/reviews/ankara-review-1203194060/) "a cryptic, ironical fadeout." This implies at least one reviewer considers the intent to be somehow ironical. Did they imagine that had the passengers not given up hope, they  - or their species at least - would be OK? I take that interpretation with a grain of salt given the span of time they would have had to endure, and the finite amount of energy this sunless voyage afforded them. The intent of the film was very clear to me that humanity at least would end. It remains an extinction event; nowhere to go to, and nowhere to return to.

But the fact does remain that the poem ends in complete endless drifting, and the film included that clip, for one reason or another, and that clip is never once even spoken about on the Internet. At this early point in the film's life cycle we only have deductive reasoning.

The film industry in general does not like dead ends, as director Pella Kågerman notes in an [interview with Cautionspoilers.com](https://www.cautionspoilers.com/interviews/aniara-directors-pella-kagerman-hugo-lilja/) last month. When asked why this classic story has not been adapted to film before, Pella responded:

> Pella: I think because it is so dark, it’s hard to get money for it, so we had to work a lot with hope. The only demand that the daughters of the writer had, was for us not to change the ending.
>
> At one point we actually pitched this film in Hollywood for a famous agent and he was following the story until we came to the end, where he was like, “But one survives…”
>
> SARAH: They’ll always say you’ve got to have a survivor, or a dog survives, or something like that.

So there was certainly pressure for this adaptation to carry something forward, if for no better reason than to make room for a sequel (pronounced: $$$$). As mentioned earlier, this film is young, and the social pressure to remain true to Martinson's theme are very compelling.  Putting down in ink that you just made a movie about the cycle of life would be tantamount to sacrilege.

There are other interpretations which share the sense that the story at least deserves a cycle rather than a finality:

A contemporary adaptation of the poem - which is in fact 103 poems, or cantos - was conducted by [The Crossing Choir](https://www.crossingchoir.org/) which notes a connection between the Matteson story and Asian mythology, and choreographer Antti Silvennoinen

> I had talked with [artistic] director [Donald Nally] there's a connection
> between Aniara and asian mythology and culture so I'm gonna use
> some ideas of Taoism for example very circular movements and sort of
> martial arts based energy

Taoist practitioners believe in a [circular "path of return"](https://www.learnreligions.com/taoist-visual-symbols-4123169)—a movement from the myriad things of the world back into wuji. The Immortals, or those who have entered the Tao, are those who have completed this "path of return." A Taoist interpretation of the poem would be inclined to extend the poem's forever drifting toward Lira out to arriving at Lira, and a circular path from the manifest Taiji and the unmanifest Wuji, via the mechanism of Taiji, and then back in the definitive yin and yang cycle enveloping all things.

If this final scene depicts panspermia, it would the accidental panspermia [proposed in 1960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panspermia#cite_note-76) by astronomy professor Thomas Gold. What arrived in Lyra may well have contained viable Earthly microorganisms. According to [Wikipedia there are documented viable Earthly bacterial spores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panspermia#Extremophiles) that are 40 million years old that are very resistant to radiation, and others able to resume life after being dormant for 25 million years,

So no canonical answer agrees that the clip in question had the intent to convey panspermia, and even if it were true no such agreement will likely be printed; modern science does not reject the possibility that accidental panspermia would be the outcome of this version of the film.

Answer (score 6):

It certainly wasn't intended in the *original* source poem. That ends with the mima worshippers sitting huddled against the encroaching darkness, then eventually dying and turning to dust as their "sarcophagus" continues to hurtle through space for thousands more years.

There's no good indication that their bones ever come to rest, anywhere other than the inky black of space.

> In our immense sarcophagus we lay
>   as on into the empty seas we passed 
>   where cosmic night, forever cleft from day,
>   around our grave a glass-clear silence cast.
>
> Around the mima’s grave we sprawled in rings,
>   fallen and to guiltless ashes changed,
>   delivered from the stars’ embittered stings.
>   And through us all Nirvana’s current ranged.

This final view of the passengers (and their bones as dust) appears to be what the makers wanted to be true to.

Comment: That's nothing like how the film ended. I'm surprised the family allowed this change. Certainly they were not "forever cleft from day."

Comment: @VogonPoet - Ending a film on a total downer is rarely good for financial reasons.

Comment: I get that but they still disregarded the family's condition

Comment: @VogonPoet - Well, we don't know what was agreed with the family. It might have been as simple as "don't give it a happyt ending", which they certainly didn't.

Comment: I guess I need to edit to exclude the poem. The film certainly saw daylight again. No idea about the opera

Comment: @VogonPoet - I'm pretty sure we've been through this already. You can't change a question **after its been answered** because you realise you don't like the scope.

Comment: This question only concerned the film until Inquest led me to believe all versions were consistent. [See my original post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/221118/2), your answer should at leat attempt to address the OP intent, and your edits should not be done to merely prevent improved quality. How about working to avoid another edit war?

Comment: Observations
(1) The last chapter is called The Sarcophagus and shows the Aniara visibly dead but intact. Algae could have survived but it doesn't look like it, and the poem is about people, not algae.
(2) The music at the end is upbeat, which has not been mentioned. Either this is mockery at humanity's well-earned despair, or it is literal and signals some good. 
(3) Based on its coloration (is that an active carbon-oxygen cycle?) the planet looks like it may already have plant life. But this is a guess, and besides the only way to imply a planet is habitable is to paint it green and blue.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing hopeful about the ending.

> In the version of the film I saw on Hulu, the ship is dark, the passengers long dead. After nearly six million years (the title card reads “Year 5,981,407”), it happens to pass near an Earth-like planet. The interior shots of the ship show ice encrusted surfaces and bits of junk floating in zero G.

Even without attempting to deduce authorial intent, I’m not sure how that ending in any way implies panspermia.

Comment: It implies it because material from the inhabitants may still live on.

Answer (score -1):

I took the ending to mean they finally approached a planet that yould allow them to turn around with a gravity assist, but the tragedy is that it took six million years to stumble upon one, and that is, sadly, the nature of chance. The astronomer alluded to this when she spoke of the bubble in the glass and how vast space really is.

I also think the spear revealed that even though they got "lucky" and had a chance encounter with an ultra rare, promising object, it ultimately meant nothing and added to the dread of hopelessness. I don't think there were any other implications with the spear other than to illustrate that hope and faith are rather meaningless and the universe doesn't care about us any more than it does a space rock.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm afraid the question was quite specific about wanting only official or canonical sources to answer the question if *Aniara* had seeded Earth-originated life on the new planet.